# how to update session data in Laravel (session cart)

Tags: shopping-cart, laravel-7, laravel-session

i am making an e commerce shopping cart where i have used session to store cart item. But the problem is when i am trying to update (increase or decrease) cart item's **quantity** i am not getting the accurate total price. i am trying to update the whole cart not by single item...

## This is update function in cart Model

```
    public function update($id, $qty){
        //reset qty and price in the cart
        $this->totalQty -= $this->items[$id]['qty'];
        $this->totalPrice -= $this->items[$id]['price'] * $this->items[$id]['qty'];

        //add item with new qty
        $this->items[$id]['qty'] = $qty;

        //total price and total qty in cart
        $this->totalQty += $qty;
        $this->totalPrice += $this->items[$id]['price'] * $qty;
    }
```

## This is update function in controller

```
    //update cart
    public function updateQty(Request $request){
        $id = $request->item_id;
        $qty = $request->qty;

        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;

        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

        for ($i=0; $i <count($id) ; $i++) { 
            $cart->update($id[$i], $qty[$i]);
            Session::put('cart', $cart);
        }


        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## The cart

[cart image in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeYUF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should go outside the `for` loop.

```
Session::put('cart', $cart);
```

I will be surprised if this solves your problem but definitely something that you need to fix.

Also I don't understand the `echo` part in your `for` loop. Remove the `echo` and give it a try.

```
echo($cart->update($id[$i], $qty[$i]));
$cart->update($id[$id], $qty[$i]);
```

Also providing the `constructor` for `Cart` model in the question would be a good idea.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I've already solved the the problem.. btw i was checking what my Cart model is returning by doing the echo in for loop. i forgot to remove it from the question

Comment: Do post how you solved your issue and what exactly the issue was. Would be helpful for others.

Comment: i will keep it mind next time.. btw the problem i was facing, (as mentioned in the question)  wherever i was trying to update the cart item's, the total price of the cart item's was not showing accurately... i solved it by removing the cart and create a new cart with updated quantity of cart items.